# setting up nodejs on sharing host

Tags: node.js, apache, hosting, cpanel, shared-hosting

how setting up nodejs on sharing host? 
nodejs and git installed on my host and I access to ssh , but when I want to run my application , apache handle those routes. 
I read some article but those said fix with httpd.conf and I don't access to httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

If you have the proper permissions you can forward all the traffic from port 80 that apache handles to the port that your node app is running. You can find examples on google if you search for keywords like apache, vhosts and reverse proxy.